# why form validation is giving this error Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi i'm getting this `error`

> Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent
>   formGroup directive

i'm trying to do the basic validation for `form` `inputs`

**here is my `form`**

```
<form [formGroup]="formgroup">

   <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="firstname" [(ngModel)]= "userData.firstname" ></ion-input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item *ngIf="firstname.hasError('required') && firstname.touched">
        <p>*First Name Is Required</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="lastname" [(ngModel)]= "userData.lastname" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

   <ion-item *ngIf="lastname.hasError('required') && lastname.touched">
        <p>*First Name Is Required</p>
   </ion-item>  

</form>
```

**here is my controller code**

```
import  {FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators,AbstractControl,FormControl} from '@angular/forms'; 

    export class Form1Page {

      formgroup:FormGroup;
      firstname:AbstractControl;
      lastname:AbstractControl;

      userData = {"firstname":"", "lastname":""};  

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

        this.formgroup = formBuilder.group({
                 firstname:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)],
                 lastname:['',Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(15)]
        });

        this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['firstname'];

        this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['lastname'];

        this.userData.dateOfBirth = new Date().toISOString();
      }

}
```

please help me to get rid of these `error`

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have misstyped controls. You 2 times assign to the `firstname`, so your `lastname` stays not initialized. Change the second one to the `lastname`.

Replace

```
 this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['firstname'];
 this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['lastname'];
```

with

```
this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['firstname'];
this.lastname = this.formgroup.controls['lastname'];
```

Documentation for [**Angular Reactive Forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: ya it is correct +1 for that but now my `error` has changed to this `Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive`

Comment: ya thats right but i'm a total beginner with `ionic 3`, please help me with update answer

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ejqbwz?file=pages/home/home.html `Validators.minLength(5)` is async validator in his case. I used `Validators.compose` to combine sync validators. But i didn't see the error he is talking about

Comment: `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive`

Comment: @yurzui, please post your answer, so that i respect your answer